# an issue about binding data with model in sub loop in the vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to bind data with model in the vue but I've got an problem if I try to bind data in nested loops.

This is example how I try do it. In result I expect to see all checkboxes are selected, but its don't work and I don't get why?

example https://jsfiddle.net/zmum6cnw/

```
<div id="element">

<div v-for="filter in filters">
    {{filter.name}}
    <div v-for="option in filter.options">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="option.status">
        {{option.name}}
    </div>
</div> 
<pre>
    {{filters | json}}
</pre>
```

```
var obj = new Vue({
    el: '#element',
    data: {         
        filters: [
        {
            name: '#1',
            options: [
                {
                    checked: true,
                    name: 'A'
                },
                {
                    checked: true,
                    name: 'B'
                },
                {
                    checked: true,
                    name: 'C'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: '#2',
            options: [
                {
                    checked: true,
                    name: 'A'
                },
                {
                    checked: true,
                    name: 'B'
                },
                {
                    checked: true,
                    name: 'C'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]}
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input tag as:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="option.status" checked = option.checked>
```

Comment: I should change to "<input type="checkbox" v-model="option.checked">"